# Ejecutar tareas en Apache2

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2

Tengo una aplicación hecha con Django corriendo en un servidor Ubuntu con Apache2.

Necesito crear un proceso que se esté ejecutando constantemente para comprobar algunos datos de la DB y ejecutar algunas funciones según sus valores si fuese necesario hacerlo.

Así que mis dudas son:

Realizo la tarea en el servidor como tal? Es decir, con algun modulo de Apache que permita correr una tarea infinitamente? o Uso alguna librería de Django ( si existe ) para ejecutar tareas sin necesidad de peticiones del usuario?

De poderse hacer, como se haría?

Espero que haya quedado claro, gracias

Comment: en realidad la tarea es de django porque menciones apache2?, puedes agregar la ruta al crontab y listo

Comment: @JackNavaRow muchas gracias, provaré a ver qué tal :D

Comment: Quizás te interese echarle un vistazo a `celery` y a `django-celery`, es el gestor de tareas más famoso de python.